# Electron-builder Error: Application directory dist doesn't exists

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, electron, electron-builder

The app built a couple of years ago using:

- Angular v5.2.0
- Angular-CLI v1.6.4
- Electron v1.7.8
- Electron Builder v20.0.5
- Node 10.15.0
- NPM 6.4.1
- node-gyp 3.8.0

It was last compiled in September 2019 but now when run `npm i` after cloning from the repo getting the following error on electron-builder. Running on Windows 10 and Visual Studio Code. I've got the same error on MacOS Catalina.

```
PS C:\[Project\directory]> npm i      
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade t

> [projectname-version]-beta postinstall C:\Pinro\8track-player
> electron-builder install-app-deps

  • electron-builder version=20.0.5
  • loaded configuration file=C:[project\directory]\electron-builder.json
Error: Application directory dist doesn't exists
    at C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder-lib\src\util\config.ts:140:13
From previous event:
    at computeDefaultAppDirectory (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder-lib\out\util\config.js:131:22)
    at C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\src\cli\install-app-deps.ts:52:78
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at installAppDeps (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\out\cli\install-app-deps.js:51:21)
    at then (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\src\cli\cli.ts:48:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
From previous event:
    at Object.args [as handler] (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\src\cli\cli.ts:48:33)
    at Object.runCommand (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:235:44
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\node_modules\yargs\yargs.
    at Object.get [as argv] (C:\[project\directory]\node_modules\electron-builder\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:965:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\[project\directory]node_modules\electron-builder\src\cli\cli.ts:42:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! [project-name-version]-beta postinstall: `electron-builder install-app-deps`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the [project-name-version]-beta postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\[Project directory]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-12T07_25_33_106Z-debug.log
PS C:\[Project\directory]>
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "[project-name]",
  "version": "[version-number]-beta",
  "description": "",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular 5",
    "electron",
    "typescript",
    "sass"
  ],
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "start": "tsc main.ts && npm-run-all --parallel webpack:watch electron:serve",
    "webpack:watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start:web": "webpack-dev-server --content-base . --port 4200 --inline",
    "build:electron:main": "tsc main.ts --outDir dist && copyfiles package.json dist && cd dist && npm install --prod && cd ..",
    "build": "webpack --display-error-details && npm run build:electron:main",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run build",
    "electron:serve": "npm run build:electron:main && electron ./dist --serve",
    "electron:test": "electron ./dist",
    "electron:dev": "npm run build && electron ./dist",
    "electron:prod": "npm run build:prod && electron ./dist",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && npx electron-builder build --mac",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3 -v 1.8",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet && npm run build",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "3.5.20",
    "electron-builder-squirrel-windows": "20.0.5",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/tarball/master"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
    "@types/node": "^7.10.2",
    "amplitudejs": "^3.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.1.1",
    "copyfiles": "1.2.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "cross-env": "5.0.5",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "cssnano": "3.10.0",
    "diskspace": "^2.0.0",
    "electron": "^1.8.8",
    "electron-builder": "20.0.5",
    "electron-builder-squirrel-windows": "20.0.5",
    "electron-json-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "electron-log": "^2.2.14",
    "electron-reload": "1.2.2",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "is-online": "^7.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-vibrant": "^3.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "npx": "^9.7.1",
    "os-name": "^2.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "6.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "postcss-url": "7.1.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "replace": "^0.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "script-loader": "0.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "stylus-loader": "3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.0.0",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "wait-on": "^2.1.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "1.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.17"
  },
  "files": [
    "*.js",
    "build",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.0"
  }
}
```

**electron-builder.json:**

```
{
  "productName": "[Project name]",
  "appId": "[ID]",
  "directories": {
    "app": "dist",
    "output": "app-builds"
  },
  "win": {
    "icon": "dist/favicon",
    "target": [
      "squirrel"
    ]
  },
  "mac": {
    "icon": "dist/favicon",
    "target": [
      "dmg"
    ]
  },
  "linux": {
    "icon": "dist",
    "target": [
      "AppImage"
    ]
  }
}
```

What I have done so far:

Windows 10:

1. Installed Node 10.15.0 and NPM 6.4.1
2. node-gyp 3.8.0
3. windows-build-tools

Can you please suggest any solution to run the app? Thanks in advance.

[Error debug log - screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyQZU.png)

Comment: Can you run it with 'npm start' or 'electron .'?

Comment: Got the error immediately after cloning local machine and run npm i

Comment: I got through the npm i command by fixing the "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "" params on the package.json

Comment: I'm still getting the error at this line: > electron-builder install-app-deps

  • electron-builder version=20.0.5
  • loaded configuration file=/Users/[file/directory]/electron-builder.json
Error: Application directory dist doesn't exists